# Get max values from each array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

So I have data like this:

```
data = [
         [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39}, {a: "bb", value: 150}],
         [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83}, {a: "ccc", value: 12}],
         [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9}, {a: "dd", value: 1}]
       ]
```

I want to get max values of value in each array of objects. So the result should be like this:

```
maxValues = [150, 83, 55]
```

Right now my code is:

```
let maxValues = []
let tmp;
let highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

data.map((eachArr, index) => {
  for(let i = eachArr.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    tmp = eachArr[i].value;
    if(tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
  }
  maxValues.push(highest)
})
```

and the result is

```
maxValues = [150, 150, 150]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the syntax errors (no closing `}` character for each of the objects) present in your real code, or is that a typo here?

Comment: `data = [
         [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39, {a: "bb", value: 150],
         [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83, {a: "ccc", value: 12],
         [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9, {a: "dd", value: 1]
       ]` not in right format, please have a look

Comment: Seems like a Typo ... I suggested an edit ... If not, then the user has bigger problems !

Comment: @Addy: I saw, and rejected, that edit: please don't 'correct' code in a question (unless the OP specifically confirms a given typo), in many instances the typo can be the problem, and changing, or correcting, the code then hides the reason for the question being asked. (Also I rolled back the edit which, for some reason, was approved. Sorry, it really is nothing personal though.)

Comment: All clear ... shall keep that in mind.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry. it was a typo. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Addy Thank you for an edit, and it was a typo. thanks again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and take the max of mapped `value`.

> The **spread syntax** allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.

```js
var data = [[{ a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39 }, {a: "bb", value: 150 }], [{ a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83 }, {a: "ccc", value: 12 }], [{ a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9 }, {a: "dd", value: 1 }]],
    result = data.map(a => Math.max(...a.map(b => b.value)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I realise you've posted this recently, but could you take the time to explain what the code does, and how it works? That way, hopefully, it's of more use to future visitors. Beautifully written, by the way! :)

Comment: I would also appreciate an explanation .. that'd be like a cherry on top ... and save me the time googling how this works .-)

Comment: The spread operator `...` ain't hard to unnderstand, she includes the link, don't be lazy people :D

Answer (score 7):

You have to include `let highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;` inside `forEach` function, because you have to set `highest` from every set in your `array`.

```js
data = [
         [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39}, {a: "bb", value: 150}],
         [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83}, {a: "ccc", value: 12}],
         [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9}, {a: "dd", value: 1}]
       ]
let maxValues = []
let tmp;
data.forEach((eachArr, index) => {
  let highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  for(let i = eachArr.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    tmp = eachArr[i].value;
    if(tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
  }
  maxValues.push(highest)
})
console.log(maxValues);
```

Comment: `map` is being abused here. The code should use `forEach`, or should actually use the result of `map` (e.g., `let maxValues = data.map(...);` where the callback returns `highest`).

Answer (score 4):

Ecmascript 5 solution with `Math.max.apply()` and `Array.prototype.map()` functions:

```js
var data = [
    [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39}, {a: "bb", value: 150}],
    [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83}, {a: "ccc", value: 12}],
    [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9}, {a: "dd", value: 1}]
];

var maxValues = data.map(function (arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function(o){ return o.value; }));
});

console.log(maxValues);
```

**Math.max.apply()** function will return the largest of the given numbers.
 The numbers(`value` attribute of each nested object) are accumulated via **Array.prototype.map()** function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: While the code is good, a *useful* answer *explains* what you did and why.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the array using  [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), to generate the array element find out an object which contains the largest value using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then retrieve its value property.

```
data.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? b : a).value)
```

```js
data = [
  [{
    a: "b",
    value: 12
  }, {
    a: "bb",
    value: 39
  }, {
    a: "bb",
    value: 150
  }],
  [{
    a: "c",
    value: 15
  }, {
    a: "cc",
    value: 83
  }, {
    a: "ccc",
    value: 12
  }],
  [{
    a: "d",
    value: 55
  }, {
    a: "dd",
    value: 9
  }, {
    a: "dd",
    value: 1
  }]
]

console.log(
  data.map((arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? b : a).value)
)
```

---

Without [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
data.map(function(arr){
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a.value < b.value ? b : a
  }).value;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [underscore max function](http://underscorejs.org/#max)

**Whitout ES6**

```
_(data).map( function (item){
   var max = _(item).max( function( hash ){ return hash.value })
   return max.value
});
```

**With ES6**

```
_(data).map((item) => _(item).max(( hash ) => hash.value).value);
```